# Who was the first manager to get expelled from a match in the history of football?

Tags: football, trivia, history

Who was the first manager to get expelled from a match in the history of football?
(First event that was recorded and reported.)

A recent example: [Jose-Mourinho](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/sport/football/teams/chelsea/11953231/Jose-Mourinho-in-meltdown-after-red-card-and-defeat-at-West-Ham-pile-on-misery-for-Chelsea-manager.html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the book [Football Oddities](https://books.google.com/books?id=TaM7AwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Tony Matthews, under the section "Discipline", subsection "Football League" where Mr. Matthews lists various random-ish facts:

"The first manager to be sent off in a League game was [Ronnie Rooke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronnie_Rooke), as playermanager of Crystal Palace v Millwall in October 1949."